# GROUP BY and create columns for each unique value grouped on (output as 1 row always), then use the output as a JOIN - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, case, conditional-aggregation

I need to GROUP data BY 2 columns (BillingId and PaymentType) - no issues with that AND **have output of 1 row with columns of unique PaymentType** - issue with this step. So each BillingId has only 1 row and that table will be used for joining another Tables in the Database.

**Billing Table:**

```
BillingId (unique)

 12345
 67890
```

**Payment Table:**

```
PaymentId PaymentType  BillingId PaymentAmount
 (unique)

   12      electronic    12345      62.29
   14      electronic    12345      73.28
   56      electronic    12345     -62.29
   6       electronic    67890      83.58
   2       adjustment    67890      30.43
```

**MY CODE:**

```
SELECT GroupedTable.* 

FROM (SELECT b.BillingId, 
             p.PaymentType, 
             SUM(p.PaymentAmount) AS AmountPaid
      FROM Billing AS b
      LEFT JOIN Payment AS p
        ON (b.BillingId = p.BillingId)
      GROUP BY b.BillingId, p.PaymentType) AS GroupedTable
```

**OUTPUT (obviously incorrect):**

```
  BillingId  PaymentType   AmountPaid

     67890    electronic    83.58
     12345    electronic    73.28
     67890    adjustment    30.43
```

**OUTPUT I NEED:**

```
BillingId    AmountPaid     AmountAdjusted 
            (electronic)     (adjustment)

  67890         83.58           30.43
  12345         73.28            0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should group by `BillingId` only and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT b.BillingId, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.PaymentType = 'electronic' THEN p.PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS AmountPaid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.PaymentType = 'adjustment' THEN p.PaymentAmount ELSE 0 END) AS AmountAdjusted
FROM Billing AS b LEFT JOIN Payment AS p
ON b.BillingId = p.BillingId
GROUP BY b.BillingId;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83c1509207238b15fc645c8230c68f80).

Answer (score 6):

It looks easier if you use `Case When` expressions as follows:

```
Select B.BillingId, Sum(Case When P.PaymentType='electronic' Then P.PaymentAmount End) As [AmountPaid (electronic)],
                    Sum(Case When P.PaymentType='adjustment' Then P.PaymentAmount End) As [AmountAdjusted (adjustment)] 
From Billing As B Left Join Payment As P On (B.BillingId=P.BillingId)
Group by B.BillingId
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e46927198f8aaf254bbe0700e49ade45)

| BillingId | AmountPaid (electronic) | AmountAdjusted (adjustment) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 73,28 | NULL |
| 67890 | 83,58 | 30,43 |